# Leetcode－why my code is way slower even though it is also O(n)?

Tags: python-3.x

I run into my second leetcode question:first unique char in a string.
Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
def firstUniqChar(self, s: str) -> int:
    for index, elem in enumerate(s):
        if s.count(elem)==1:
            return index
    return -1
```

I noticed the running time is slow. I also checked the solution hint, suggesting using a hashmap.

[image]

I tried the Hashmap way, aka hm. My hashmap solution did go thru with much faster speed. But I don't know why. I assume both of my solutions are O(n). Also as a rookie who just started to learn algorithms, speed complexity matters more than space complexity, right? Because memory is so cheap nowadays.

```
class Solution:
def firstUniqChar(self, s: str) -> int:
    hm = {}

    for char in s:
        hm[char] = hm.get(char, 0) + 1

    for key,val in hm.items():
        if val == 1:
            return s.index(key)

    return -1
```

[image]

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Pay attention to indentation, because badly indented python code is invalid code. Your first solution is _not_ O(n). `str.count()` itself is O(n). You invoke `str.count()` `n` times, making your solution O(n^2)

Comment: Big O is only a rough guide. There can be plenty of variance even if two solutions have the same Big O. For example `Thread.sleep(1)` and `Thread.sleep(1000000)` are both constant time: O(1). One is clearly faster than the other.

Comment: A minor improvement to your hashmap solution: enumerate in the first loop and use a second dictionary, `idxs` to store the latest index of each char, simply overwriting the last (doesn't matter for duplicates) and then in the second loop when `val == 1`, you'd `return idxs[key]`.

Comment: @ddejohn Thank you so much for your advice.